# Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, androidx, nestedscrollview

I am using NestedScrollView and I am getting error  Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.I also tried android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView. But both don't work and getting error. In the nested scrollview there is linear layout and in linear layout, there is one imageview, one textview and recycler view. Is there any dependency that I have to add to use for NestedScrollView? Please help in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddFriend"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_group"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Group Members"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
2020-04-19 11:07:08.404 32661-32661/com.example.chatapp10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chatapp10, PID: 32661
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chatapp10/com.example.chatapp10.GroupMembersActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.chatapp10.GroupMembersActivity.onCreate(GroupMembersActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingChildHelper.setNestedScrollingEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(NestedScrollView.java:260)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5395)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:87)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.<init>(NestedScrollView.java:198)
        at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.<init>(NestedScrollView.java:193)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.chatapp10.GroupMembersActivity.onCreate(GroupMembersActivity.java:41) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` from NestedSrcollView and add it to RecyclerView, It should work fine.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Group Members"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```